# What's the difference between implementing func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nsurlsession

In a background session, for an app<>server communication using https, what is the difference between a fairly relaxed implementation of the following method, **or none at all**?

```
  func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
    completionHandler(.useCredential, challenge.proposedCredential)
  }
```

In both cases the app works, but I've read about each invocation of this method incrementing the Resume Rate Limit of the app (which is supposedly bad)

So yeah, after I realized that the app just works without any implementation of this method, I started asking myself what is the reason for possibly implementing it? Authorization is done via 401 and a subsequent login.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think some useful information could be found from documentation [Performing Manual Server Trust Authentication](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system/handling_an_authentication_challenge/performing_manual_server_trust_authentication):

> **To perform manual server trust authentication**, implement the
>   URLSessionDelegate method urlSession(_:didReceive:completionHandler:).

Following with:

> In most cases, you should let the URL Loading System’s default
>   handling evaluate the server trust. **You get this behavior when you
>   either don’t have a delegate** or don’t handle authentication
>   challenges.

And to explain why you might need to do a manual server trust authentication, thus by implementing the URLSessionDelegate method `urlSession(_:didReceive:completionHandler:)`:

> **However, performing your own evaluation may be useful for scenarios
>   like the following:**
>
> You want to accept server credentials that would otherwise be rejected
>   by the system. For example, your app makes a secure connection to a
>   development server that uses a self-signed certificate, which would
>   ordinarily not match anything in the system’s trust store.
>
> You want to reject credentials that would otherwise be accepted by the
>   system. For example, you want to “pin” your app to a set of specific
>   keys or certificates under your control, rather than accept any valid
>   credential.